# How to configure interval and max_attempts in aws S3 javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws S3 nodejs sdk and I need to check if a file exist in my bucket as quickly as possible.

The default params of the AWS.S3.waitFor() method check to object existence every 5 seconds with 20 attempts max. I would need to check it every 2 seconds if possible. I can change the configuration file (s3-2006-03-01.waiters.json) to achieve that but I'm looking for a programmatic way to do it. Is there any way to achieve that ? My code looks like this for the moment:

```js
    s3.waitFor('objectExists',{
              Bucket : 'XXXXX',
              Key : _Key,
            },function (err){

                  if(err){
                    return _callback(err);
                  }
                  return _callback(false);

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this date (July 28th, 2016), there's no way of customizing these two options. There's a [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/881) on Github AWS SDK for JS repository for that.